# How can I retrieve string from plist?

Tags: ios, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

i have a plist named as "config.plist"[image: config.plist] in xcode ,i tried to retrieve register url (key :reg ) but when i print that result it showing null value?

This is my code to retrieve string ..please refer image for my plist structure.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [[_config objectForKey:@"URL"] objectForKey:@"reg"]]];
```

Comment: Where do you store your plist file ?

Comment: updates: its in my xcode

Comment: what is Xcode? that is an IDE, that does not store any plist at all.

Comment: If you say it's in your xcode, i think you added it as a resource...

Comment: please search the `config.plist` in spotlight, and send us the full path.

Comment: its in my resource folder..i ididnt write any codes for creating plist

Comment: If you drag some plist to your xcode it will be in resource folder

Comment: Resource means NSBundle mainBundle.... so my code shoudl work

Comment: Anoop ur codes all are working for me  except this...yar

Comment: I guess there is some issue with your file copy. Make sure it should not referenced out side of your bundle resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code

```
NSString *plistFilePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *urlDictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
NSString *urlString=[[urlDictionary objectForKey:@"URL"] valueForKey:@"reg"];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *plist=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plist];
NSString *stringValue=dict[@"URL"][@"reg"];
```

**EDIT: Very Important to understand the following:**

In the above `dict` itself is the `objectForKey:@"Root"`

And I/we trying to find by `[@"Root"][@"URL"][@"reg"]` which is not there.

So for readability with namingConventions(what it stores) it should be :

```
NSString *plist=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *rootDict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plist];
NSString *stringValue=dict[@"URL"][@"reg"];
```

Or, even

```
NSString *plist=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *stringValue=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plist][@"URL"][@"reg"];
```

Comment: I see your update... change the path as suggested by Bhargavi in George's answer

Comment: It's because you commented that it is in the documents directory,look at the edit on the top

Comment: usually you store plists in mainBundle so we sovled that way only.

Comment: @Viral Hey that is syntax of objective -c :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Iam able to get my path and dictionary values from ur codes ,but when i print  "stringValue" it shows null values

Comment: @akh Please don't try to vandalize Anoop's answer. There's a reason he used code formatting, you don't have to revert it back to plain-text formatting (which is wrong). Rejected your edit.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya There was nothing wrong with your answer, Akh attempted to make an invalid edit to it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"config.plist"]; 
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *result = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Root"] objectForKey:@"URL"]objectForKey:@"reg"];
```

**Edit** for Resource:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: If it is stored in the documents, look how Bhargavi edited my answer

Comment: @George please alert path again . He has within its mainBundle not in doc dir

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *plist=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"config" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"path%@",plist);
    NSDictionary *dict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plist];
    NSLog(@"d%@",dict);
    NSString *stringValue=[[dict objectForKey:@"URL"] valueForKey:@"reg"];
```

This thing works for me..Thanks for your all help

Comment: mail your plist file to me, if no issues in sending. find my mail id on profile